# Getting Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] in ng-repeat using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting the following error while i have no data using ng-repeat in Angular.js

> Error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=user%20in%20objHodUserData&p1=string%3Al&p2=l
    at Error (native)
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:6:416
    at http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:279:39
    at Object.fn (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:129:128)
    at n.$digest (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:130:206)
    at n.$apply (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:133:236)
    at g (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:87:376)
    at K (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:91:448)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (http://oditek.in/Gofasto/js/angularjs.js:92:462)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="user in objHodUserData ">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{user.user_name}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
<td>{{user.mob_no}}</td>
<td>{{user.login_name}}</td>
<td ng-if="user.user_status==1">Enable</td>
<td ng-if="user.user_status==0">Disable</td>
<td>
<a ui-sref='hod.user'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editUserData(user.user_id)" >  
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a ui-sref='hod.user'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Delete' ng-click="deleteUserData(user.user_id);" >  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
```

When the object `objHodUserData` has no data these type error is coming.I tried to resolve this by using  `track by $index`. By using this error has gone but 4 blank rows are generating.Here i need when there is no data present no rows will generate without any error and when data will be there it will display.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like your objHodUserData array has 4 empty values on it. Have you checked the content of the array?

Comment: I assume you found a solution to this? Perhaps the best solution would be to not allow null values to be inserted in the list in the first place, then you will not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by wrapping all the `<tbody>` within a `<div>` element. 
and inserting ng-show in this div element like that

```
<div ng-show="hasElements()">
```

and in your controller you have a $scope function to check if there is elements in the object like that:

```
$scope.hasElements = function(){
return objHodUserData.length ===0; 
}
```

and that should work.

let me if it solved your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: if i not mistaken, `ng-show` not  prevent running `ng-repeat`

Comment: you can replace it with ng-if if you like, because the ng-if will remove all the DOM element.

Comment: i mean: in your case OP should still get his error with duplicated items

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using lodash, then this is a handy utility library for your javascript, which can help with tasks like this.

```
var objHodUserDataWithoutBlanks = _.filter(objHodUserData, function(n) {
  return n.user_name != "";
});
```

The above will filter out entries that have a blank username. Then your ng-repeat can instead repeat over this object without blanks: `objHodUserDataWithoutBlanks`.

Edit: Alternate method using only angularjs:

Add an angular filter:

```
myApp.filter('nonBlankOnly', function() {
  return function( items) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(item.user_name != "") {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Then apply the filter in your controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
    $scope.objHodUserDataWithoutBlanks = $filter('nonBlankOnly')(objHodUserData);
}
```

And repeat through filtered items:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in objHodUserDataWithoutBlanks">
```

Comment: Note: you don't need to use a lodash filter, you could also use an angular filter to achieve this. I find lodash easier to work with for these utility type tasks.

Comment: Updated answer - angular only way in edit is probably cleaner solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use de ng-show to check if there is an existing user, something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in objHodUserData ">
<td ng-show="user">{{$index+1}}</td>
<td ng-show="user">{{user.user_name}}</td>
<td ng-show="user">{{user.email}}</td>
<td ng-show="user">{{user.mob_no}}</td>
<td ng-show="user">{{user.login_name}}</td>
```

or if you prefer to hide the entire row, put the ng-show on the `<tr>` element.

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="user in objHodUserData " ng-show="user">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{user.user_name}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
<td>{{user.mob_no}}</td>
<td>{{user.login_name}}</td>
<td ng-if="user.user_status==1">Enable</td>
<td ng-if="user.user_status==0">Disable</td>
<td>
<a ui-sref='hod.user'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editUserData(user.user_id)" >  
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a ui-sref='hod.user'>
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Delete' ng-click="deleteUserData(user.user_id);" >  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-if along with ng-repeat.It should be ng-if="objHodUserData.length !=0"

Comment: can you confirm if objHodUserData is an array and not an object.If not make it an array and then try